# How do I use CMake on OS X, target the new Arm M1

Tags: macos, cmake, apple-m1

I have some dependencies that use cmake I need to compile and I am not sure I am doing this correctly. I am currently using `-march=x86-64` in my CFLAGS for amd64 which seems to work, but I'm not sure that's correct because it is not working when I try targeting the new M1.  Is there something else I should be doing to target different architectures with cmake from the command line?

```
export CFLAGS="-O2 -march=aarch64 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -pipe"

cmake -B ${{github.workspace}}/build \
    -G "Unix Makefiles" \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${{github.workspace}}/dist/darwin/arm64 \
    -D CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON \
    -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
    -D BUILD_DEMO=ON

cmake --build ${{github.workspace}}/build \
    --parallel 2 \
    --config RelWithDebInfo \
    --clean-first

cmake --install ${{github.workspace}}/build --config RelWithDebInfo
```

**Update:** I am seeing this error.

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.4/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

"/Applications/Xcode_12.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/runner/work/project/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

error: unknown target CPU 'aarch64'
note: valid target CPU values are: nocona, core2, penryn, bonnell, atom, silvermont, slm, goldmont, goldmont-plus, tremont, nehalem, corei7, westmere, sandybridge, corei7-avx, ivybridge, core-avx-i, haswell, core-avx2, broadwell, skylake, skylake-avx512, skx, cascadelake, cooperlake, cannonlake, icelake-client, icelake-server, tigerlake, knl, knm, k8, athlon64, athlon-fx, opteron, k8-sse3, athlon64-sse3, opteron-sse3, amdfam10, barcelona, btver1, btver2, bdver1, bdver2, bdver3, bdver4, znver1, znver2, x86-64
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_72653.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_72653/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: How does it not work, is cmake throwing an error or something else? Thanks.

Comment: @firmament Updated the post with the error, it's not particularly helpful; just fails with "not able to compile a simple test program" and "unknown target CPU 'aarch64'".

Comment: It looks like you may need Xcode 12.2 and this is using 12.0

Comment: @Tsyvarev XCode presumably should be shipping with both as it is the official Apple toolchain.

Comment: So you need to tell CMake which compiler to choose. This is done via platform specification, not just via `-march` option. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879026/cmake-cross-compile-on-macos-adds-macos-sdk-to-isysroot-in-flags-make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as adding the CFLAG `-target arm64-apple-macos10.5`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES.html) variable, as I detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75623927/2137996). Setting it to `arm64` is sufficient.