# Convert CMake for compiling Apple ARM CPU

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, apple-m1

We inherited an old source code that compiles well for macOS with Intel CPU. However, it doesn't seem to indicate the architecture in the compiler flags.

What are the required changes for generating a binary compatible with Apple ARM CPU (M1/M2), **by using the same Intel-based machine**?

Here is the simplified CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyLib)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Define specific Debug settings.
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")

# Define specific Release settings.
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -D NDEBUG -O3")

# Define clang C++ defines for both Debug and Release
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra")

# Define specific Debug settings.
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")

# Define specific Release settings.
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -D NDEBUG -O3")

INCLUDE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION("^.*$")

# Defines the source code for the library
option (BUILD_TESTING "Build tests" ON)

SET(CROSSPLATFORM_SRCS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../file1.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../file2.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../file3.cpp
)

add_library(MyLib-macOS SHARED ${CROSSPLATFORM_SRCS})

#Setting properties for shared o dynamic library 
set_target_properties(MyLib-macOS
  PROPERTIES
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
  PREFIX ""
)
```

Comment: A CMake file is just a description of what to build and how to build it. The target is really irrelevant. As such if the tools exists on your system then it should be no different from building for any other system.

Comment: I have added a clarification. We are using the same machine (Intel) for producing code for M1/M2. Pretty sure we need some flags for retargeting the binary.

Comment: CMake supports [cross-compilation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html).

Comment: I know it supports cross-compilation, but it won't "guess" which is the target architecture

Comment: No it doesn't. You have to explicitly tell CMake in the toolchain file you need to write.

Comment: There are several things cmake will simply determine based on the compiler. Furthermore the cmake code here is designed in a way that allows you to specify compiler flags, e.g. by initializing the cmake variables via `-D ...` option during configuration, or better by setting them in a toolchain file; you should be using the `_INIT` versions of the variables in that case though (e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT`).

Comment: There are some very questionable things happening in the cmake logic posted here though: All the compiler options are compiler options only supported by some compilers; they should either only be added in case the compiler id matches certain criteria or moved to a toolchain file. Furthermore things like `-g` are added by cmake automatically for debug configurations and adding those yourself only serves to make the cmake project work with a smaller set of compilers. Also why attempt to set the C++ standard via cmake variable and then manually add a compiler flag for a different version???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65511230/4688321 - does this help?

Comment: You should delete the call to `include_regular_expression` as you are setting it to its default value. That line does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess with flags directly.

The variable controlling the target for macOS is [`CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES.html). It initializes the [`OSX_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OSX_ARCHITECTURES.html) target property. **Just set it to `arm64` to compile for ARM.**

There are a number of ways to do this. Here are a few, in my personal order of preference:

1. Set it at the command line via the `-D` flag.
2. Put it in a [preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html).
3. Put it in a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos).
4. Set the target property directly on a target(s) that needs it via [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) or [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html)
5. Set it as a cache variable in your project.
6. Set it as a normal variable in your project (only appropriate if *all* targets in the project *must* build for ARM).

---

For (4), here's an easy snippet to copy/paste.

```
set_target_properties(MyLib-macOS
  PROPERTIES
  OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64"
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
  PREFIX ""
)
```

---

For (5), here's an easy snippet to copy/paste. Put it after `project()`, before you create any targets.

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64"
    CACHE STRING "The list of target architectures to build")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the most complete answer, giving several alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on an M1 or M2 Mac. Make sure you're building it on MacOS 11 or later or else it won't work

```html
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyLib)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Define clang C++ defines for both Debug and Release
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra")

# Define specific Debug settings.
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")

# Define specific Release settings.
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -D NDEBUG -O3")

#ARM64 flag
if(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "x86_64")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -arch arm64")
endif()

INCLUDE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION("^.*$")

# Defines the source code for the library
option (BUILD_TESTING "Build tests" ON)

SET(CROSSPLATFORM_SRCS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../file1.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../file2.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../file3.cpp
)

add_library(MyLib-macOS SHARED ${CROSSPLATFORM_SRCS})

#Setting properties for shared o dynamic library 
set_target_properties(MyLib-macOS
  PROPERTIES
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
  PREFIX ""
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising. We will give it a try.